# I would like to display this code as a grid 1fr 1fr , but when I click on the question both sides dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display this code as a grid 1fr 1fr , but when I click on the question both sides dropdown, I tried to add class but it did not work for me any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```css
.cp-faq__section-element {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #14181c;}
    
.cp-faq__question-element {

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -2px #000;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}




.cp-faq__question-element:hover {
    background-color: #f6f7f9;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.cp-faq__question-name {
    font-family: 'hm_light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 15px 0;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .2s;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.cp-faq__section-name {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #14181c;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cp-faq__section-icon {
    float:left;  
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    i {
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
.cp-faq__question-icon {
    float:left;  
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    i {
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
.cp-faq__list-block {
    .cp-faq__questions {
    padding: 0px 2% 50px 2%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    }
}
.caret-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 30px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    .caret-outer, .caret-inner {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: -1px;
    }
    .caret-outer {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 16px solid transparent;
        border-left: 16px solid #edeff1;
    }
    .caret-inner {
        top: 4px;
        left: 2px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 14px solid transparent;
        border-left: 14px solid #ffffff;
    }
}

.cp-faq__answer {
    margin: 10px 30px;
    border-left: 2px solid @links;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: #f6f7f9;
}
.cp-faq__search {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
{assign var="title" value=$addons.cp_faq_addon.meta_title_faq_page}

{if $faq_block_id}
    {assign var="faq_pref" value=$faq_block_id}
{else}
    {if $block.block_id}
        {assign var="faq_pref" value=$block.block_id}
    {else}
        {assign var="faq_pref" value="faq_pref"}
    {/if}
{/if}
{if $show_block_searh}
    {assign var="show_block_searh" value=$show_block_searh}
{else}
    {if $addons.cp_faq_addon.show_search_comon_faq == "Y"}
        {assign var="show_block_searh" value="Y"}
    {else}
        {assign var="show_block_searh" value="N"}
    {/if}
{/if}

{if $req_no_hide_questions}
    {assign var="req_no_h_quest" value=$req_no_hide_questions}
{else}
    {assign var="req_no_h_quest" value="N"}
{/if}
{if $req_no_hide_answers}
    {assign var="req_no_h_answ" value=$req_no_hide_answers}
{else}
    {assign var="req_no_h_answ" value="N"}
{/if}

{if $no_hide_questions}
    {assign var="no_hide_questions" value=$no_hide_questions}
{else}
    {if $addons.cp_faq_addon.show_expanded_section_comon_faq == "Y"}
        {assign var="no_hide_questions" value="Y"}
    {else}
        {assign var="no_hide_questions" value="N"}
    {/if}
{/if}
{if $no_hide_answers}
    {assign var="no_hide_answers" value=$no_hide_answers}
{else}
    {if $addons.cp_faq_addon.show_expanded_questions_comon_faq == "Y"}
        {assign var="no_hide_answers" value="Y"}
    {else}
        {assign var="no_hide_answers" value="N"}
    {/if}
{/if}

{if $back_items_ids} 
    {assign var="block_items_ids" value=$back_items_ids}
{elseif $items}
    {foreach from=$items item="sect"}
        {if !$block_items_ids}
            {assign var="block_items_ids" value=$sect.back_items_ids}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/if}

{if $items}
    {assign var="all_faq_sections" value=$items}
    {if $block.properties && $block.properties.faq_show_search_form && $block.properties.faq_show_search_form == "Y"}
        {$show_block_searh="Y"}
    {else}
        {$show_block_searh="N"}
    {/if}
    {if $block.properties && $block.properties.faq_show_expanded_sec && $block.properties.faq_show_expanded_sec == "Y"}
        {assign var="no_hide_questions" value="Y"}
    {else}
        {assign var="no_hide_questions" value="N"}
    {/if}
    {if $block.properties && $block.properties.faq_show_expanded_quest && $block.properties.faq_show_expanded_quest == "Y"}
        {assign var="no_hide_answers" value="Y"}
    {else}
        {assign var="no_hide_answers" value="N"}
    {/if}
{/if}

<div id="cp_faq_sections_page_{$faq_pref}">
    <div class="cp-faq-questions__search_block">
        {if $show_block_searh && $show_block_searh == "Y"}
            <div class="ty-search-block cp-faq__search">
                <form action="{""|fn_url}" method="post" name="search_faq_sect_form" id="search_faq_sect_form" class="cm-ajax cm-submit">
                    <input type="hidden" name="result_ids" value="cp_faq_sections_page_{$faq_pref}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="is_sec_view" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" id="f_sect_view_id" name="f_sect_view_id" value="{if $block_items_ids}{$block_items_ids}{elseif $faq_section_id}{$faq_section_id}{/if}">
                    {if $no_hide_questions}
                        <input type="hidden" id="faq_hide_questions" name="faq_hide_questions" value="{$no_hide_questions}">
                    {/if}
                    {if $no_hide_answers}
                        <input type="hidden" id="faq_hide_answers" name="faq_hide_answers" value="{$no_hide_answers}">
                    {/if}
                    {if $show_block_searh}
                        <input type="hidden" id="show_block_searh" name="show_block_searh" value="{$show_block_searh}">
                    {/if}
                    {if $faq_pref}
                        <input type="hidden" id="faq_block_id" name="faq_block_id" value="{$faq_pref}">
                    {/if}
                    {strip}
                        <div id="magnifere_but">{include file="buttons/magnifier.tpl" but_name="cp_faq_addon.faq_search" alt=__("search") }</div>
                        <input type="text" name="faq_request" id="elm_faq_search_{$faq_pref}" value="{$search_back}" size="5" placeholder="{__("search")}" class="ty-search-block__input cm-hint" />
                    {/strip}
                </form>
            </div>
        {/if}
    </div>
    {if $all_faq_sections}
        <div class="cp-faq__list-block" id="all_faq_{$faq_pref}">
            {foreach from=$all_faq_sections key="sect_id" item=faq_section}
                {if $faq_section.faq_questions}
                    <div class="cm-combination cp-faq__section {if $no_hide_questions && $no_hide_questions == "N" && $req_no_h_quest && $req_no_h_quest == "N"}{else}open{/if}" id="sw_section_{$faq_section.faq_section_id}_{$faq_pref}">
                        <div class="cp-faq__section-element">
                            {if $faq_section.icon_class}
                                <div class="cp-faq__section-icon">
                                    <span><i class="cp-faq__icon {$faq_section.icon_class}"></i></span>
                                </div>                                  
                            {/if}
                            <div class="cp-faq__section-name">
                                <span>{$faq_section.faq_section_name nofilter}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="section_{$faq_section.faq_section_id}_{$faq_pref}" class="{if $no_hide_questions && $no_hide_questions == "N" && $req_no_h_quest && $req_no_h_quest == "N"}hidden{/if}">
                        <div class="cp-faq__questions">
                            <span class=" caret-top"><span class=" caret-outer"></span><span class=" caret-inner"></span></span>
                            {foreach from=$faq_section.faq_questions item="faq_question"}
                                <div class="cp-faq__question-element">
                                    <div id="sw_sec_question_{$faq_question.faq_question_id}_{$faq_pref}" class="cm-combination {if $no_hide_answers && $no_hide_answers == "N" && $req_no_h_answ && $req_no_h_answ == "N"}{else}open{/if}">
                                        {if $faq_question.qu_icon_class}
                                            <div class="cp-faq__question-icon">
                                                <span><i class="cp-faq__icon {$faq_question.qu_icon_class}"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        {/if}
                                        <div class="cp-faq__question-name">
                                            <span {if $faq_question.qu_anchor}data-scroll-id="{$faq_question.qu_anchor}"{/if} data-pref="{$faq_pref}" data-sec-id="{$faq_section.faq_section_id}" data-quest-id="{$faq_question.faq_question_id}">{$faq_question.faq_question}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cp-faq__answer ty-wysiwyg-content {if $no_hide_answers && $no_hide_answers == "N" && $req_no_h_answ && $req_no_h_answ == "N"}hidden{/if}" id="sec_question_{$faq_question.faq_question_id}_{$faq_pref}">
                                        <span>{$faq_question.faq_answer nofilter}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {/foreach}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    {else}
        <div class="cp-no-items">{__("no_data")}</div>
    {/if}
<!--cp_faq_sections_page_{$faq_pref}--></div>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var target= window.location.hash;
        var split = target.split("#");
        var data_id = split[1];
        var $target =  $('[data-scroll-id ='+data_id+']');
        var sec_id = $('[data-scroll-id ='+data_id+']').attr("data-sec-id");
        var quest_id = $('[data-scroll-id ='+data_id+']').attr("data-quest-id");
        var prefix = $('[data-scroll-id ='+data_id+']').attr("data-pref");
        $('#sec_question_'+quest_id+'_'+prefix).removeClass("hidden");
        if (sec_id) {
            $('#section_'+sec_id+'_'+prefix).removeClass("hidden");
        }
        if (quest_id) {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 30
            }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
{capture name="mainbox_title"}{if $title}{$title}{else}{__("faq_for_bread")}{/if}{/capture}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If not, this should be edited into your question instead of being posted as an answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not the answer, because I couldn't type it in the question section so I typed it here